# Could not cast value of type 'UIImage'to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, string, uiimage

I am trying to capture image by tap on captureDoc button. But when I tap on capture button I am getting an error 'could not cast value of type UIImage to NSString'. Below is my code of action button.

```
@IBAction func captureDoc(sender: AnyObject) {
    weak var weakSelf = self

    self.scanDoc.captureImageWithCompletionHander({(imageFilePath) -> Void in
        let captureImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFilePath as! String))
        captureImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.7)
        captureImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(weakSelf!.view.bounds, 0, -weakSelf!.view.bounds.size.height)
        captureImageView.alpha = 1.0
        captureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        captureImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        weakSelf?.view.addSubview(captureImageView)
        let dismissTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: weakSelf, action: #selector(self.dismissPreview))
        captureImageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
            captureImageView.frame = weakSelf!.view.bounds

            }, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

I am getting this error because I have an imageFilePath as an AnyObject but in the below statement we have to pass string. So I am really confused what to do. If anyone can figure it out whats the problem is.
Thank You!

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFilePath as! String)
```

Comment: Seems you get an image back already, not a path to an image

Comment: Yeah so now what should I do?? @Wain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you get an image back instead of the path your code expects so you can just do:

```
self.scanDoc.captureImageWithCompletionHander({(image) -> Void in
    let captureImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error of  'Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject!' to expected argument type 'UIImage?'. I have my image as AnyObject. @wain